# making the share read only

Tags: windows, storage, storage-area-network, cifs, celerra

I 'm sorry to come over again,

I was thinking of making the share read only from celerra manager( CIFS only)  by R clicking on file system.

"the NAS share (\nas12\termemployee$) to read-only to lock it from any further updates"

But , i see somebody has already mapped this network drive and then from security tab has applied the Domain Admins and has given permission to( Allow) "read and execute ,list folder contents , read" .

This has grayed out apply tab for more than an hour now.Is this the right way to do ?
Please advice , since i am worried if this is going to cause any problem.

Let me know if any elaboration is required.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not part of the Domain Admins group; and since they're the only group with an ACE, you will not be able to change the permissions. Either that or you haven't made any changes (the Apply button doesn't work if you haven't made any changes; depending on what version of Windows you're in).

Comment: it worked for me now. i have allowed "read and execute ,list folder contents , read" only.
Now my question is when the backup team will take a backup, would this be enough to make sure to change this to  read-only to lock it from any further updates . I donot 've to do any changes from celerra point of view?

Comment: The owner of the object can always override the read-only ACEs; so probably not. Why isn't your backup team using the hardware snapshot provider?

Comment: Backup team has Legato networker  and i 'm not sure if that feature is available in there.